# Height:100% not working for my image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know its been asked a million times but none of the search results seemed to work for me.

I am wondering how i can make my image to the same size as the display. I know i have to give the parent of the image a height and width so that i can use Height:100% but how can i give its parent a height and width that is different for every device?

I used position:absolute but that just made all the other content sit on top of my picture :(

am using bootstrap as well (encase you need that info)

any help would be boss! thanks!

**A lil bit of my markup**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >

**this img below to be the size of users display**

<div style="background-color:#efefef; background-image: url(/App_Themes/Biz/Images/home-main.jpg); position: static; height:100%; width:100%; background-position:center bottom; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
    <div class="container" style="height:1200px;">

        <div class="jumbotron" style="color:#fff; background-color:transparent; text-align:center;">
            <h2 style="font-weight:bold!important;">FREE rents</h2>
            <p>The easy way to rent out stuff</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" role="button" href="#moreInfoPanel" id="findOutMore">FIND OUT MORE</a> <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Account/Add-Property" role="button">rent it now</a></p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color:#eff5f7; border-top:solid 1px #e6e9ea; border-bottom:solid 1px #e6e9ea;">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="App_Themes/biz/Images/sign.png" alt=" Portals" style="padding:5% 0%; width:100%;" />
    </div>
</div>

<div>

    <div class="container" id="moreInfoPanel">

        <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="margin:60px 0px 40px 0px">
                        <div style="text-align:center; padding:10px 30px; border:solid 1px #e7ecef; border-bottom:solid 5px #e7ecef;">
                        <img src="App_Themes/biz/Images/free.png" style="margin-top:-55px;" alt="Lets Rent - FREE"  />
                        <h4>Free</h4>  

                        <p>
                            some stuff
                        </p>

                        <a href="Pricing" title="Read More - Pricing" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:-40px;" >read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="margin:60px 0px 40px 0px">
                        <div style="text-align:center; padding:10px 30px; border:solid 1px #e7ecef; border-bottom:solid 5px #e7ecef;">
                        <img src="App_Themes/biz/Images/quick.png" id="quickImage" runat="server" style="margin-top:-55px;" alt="QUICK"  />
                        <h4>Quick</h4>  

                        <p>
                           more crap
                        </p>

                        <a href="Benefits" title="Read More - Benefits" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:-40px;" >read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="margin:60px 0px 40px 0px">
                        <div style="text-align:center; padding:10px 30px; border:solid 1px #e7ecef; border-bottom:solid 5px #e7ecef;">
                        <img src="App_Themes/biz/Images/easy.png" style="margin-top:-55px;" alt="EASY"  />
                        <h4>Easy</h4>  

                        <p>
                            boom stuff here!
                        </p>

                        <a href="Benefits" title="Read More - Benefits" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:-40px;" >read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Is your body and html set to a height of 100%?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle - always the best way with css/html issues.

Comment: no i want the page to be bigger that that but just an image to be 100%. so once you see the big image you scroll down to the information

Comment: Have you set the html and body to 100%? I had the same problem two days ago and I fixed this by making the image (or image container) position:fixed; and for some reason this worked for me. I was using bootstrap aswell but I wanted my content above the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy and fast way to do this is use vh-units. Check that you have proper browser support in http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

css:

```
.full-img{
    height:100vh; /* This means 100 percent of viewport height */
    background:red;
}
```

html:

```
Above the full height block
<div class="full-img">
    <p>This takes 100% of viewport height = 100vh</p>
    <p>check http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units for browser support</p>
</div>
Below the full height block
```

Comment: i used height:100vh on the panel and the image auto made its self the size i wanted! thanks

Comment: @MikkoTapionlinna, bro I replace % with vh.. So, the image appears but when I see it in mobile, it does not responsive. I also use bootstrap. How can I do this to be responsive bro?